# Audit accesses to a JPA entity

Tags: jpa, interceptor, audit

I have a JPA **entity**, with its **attibutes** and several **NamedQueries**.

I'm trying to log some information "*any time the entity is used for something*", i.e.:

- any time any of its NamedQueries is invoked
- any time the entity is used in a Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT....FROM thisEntity a, otherEntity b WHERE.....");
- any time any of its attributes is accessed

The information i want to log must include the **invoker class name** and **invoker method**, among other.

I guess this must be achieved through **interceptors**, but i'm not sure for example if interceptors allow me to **intercept the accesses to the class throw its NamedQueries**.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that using callback methods like @PrePersist, @PostPersist, @PostLoad, @PreUpdate, @PostUpdate, @PreRemove, @PostRemove inside the entity classes.
For example

```
public class EntityA {
    ...
    @PrePersist
    public void beforePersist(){
        //Log information
    }
}
```

Additionally you could use that callback methods in listener classes.

```
public class EntityListenerA{
    @PrePersist
    public void beforePersist(EntityA ob) {
        //Log information
    }
}

@EntityListeners(EntityListenerA.class)
public class EntityA {
    ...
}
```

In your case I supose you must use the callback @PostLoad depending on the query.

Hope this help